# Delete row check sql server

Tags: sql-server, codeigniter

I am working with `code-igniter` framework.How can i check a `row deleted` from a table in `sql server`.`$this->db->affected->rows()` always returning `null`, but the row is `deleting successfully`.

Answer (score 0):

`Delete/Drop` is the most powerful command in programming. Once its executes all the database or table or row will be delete withing a very very short time.

Best practice is, add new column in your every table call `online`. To show your data filter with `WHERE online=1`. So once user press delete update it to `online=0`. So in view user understand that product has been removed from the site. But Admin knows what happen actually.

So finally you can sort out `deleted` product and `showing` products.

This what most of developers should do.

> I want to comment this on your Question. Due to high text I posted this as answer